# How to revert to a commit but keep the changes

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I've a local repo with quite a lot of changes.`git log --oneline` gives me the following history:

```
fb2d06e Included table view in posters ui
b749eb9 Final Dark theme with Posters before gitflow.
8a8e2c3 Added Dark theme, posters & only 'video' files in jsTree display
ee9b6f4 Segregated semantic dark & light themes
e3bda4c Display and save nly 'video' files
7f80737 Updated dark theme settngs in sematic UI
bf8342d Removed files Accordion
48d8719 Adding multiprocessing
```

Now, I wish to keep the changes after `bf8342d` but I dont want the commits made after them to be wiped fro history. Would be able able to revert to `bf8342d` and make it the next commit? Like this:

```
okn3wco Reverted to 'bf8342d'
fb2d06e Included table view in posters ui
b749eb9 Final Dark theme with Posters before gitflow.
8a8e2c3 Added Dark theme, posters & only 'video' files in jsTree display
ee9b6f4 Segregated semantic dark & light themes
e3bda4c Display and save nly 'video' files
7f80737 Updated dark theme settngs in sematic UI
bf8342d Removed files Accordion
48d8719 Adding multiprocessing
```

Comment: So you'd like to pretend, local file wise, that the changes in the interim commits didn't happen, sort of like changing 1 to 2, then 2 to 3, then 3 to 4, then back to 2. You want the history 1->2->3->4->2, but you'd like to stay at the value 2? Is that it?

Comment: Yep! In which way I can checkout 3,4 at anypoint of time later on

Comment: I get errors like: `error: could not revert fb2d06e... Included table view in posters ui
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'`. I tied resolving it with no success

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Unfortunately I seem to have lost some changes as well :(

Comment: I ended up using reflog to get back.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the changes in `bf8342d`, you must to make `48d8719` or `7f80737` contain the change. So the commit id after `bf8342d` will changes. Steps as below:

```
git checkout  7f80737
git checkout -b temp
git reset --soft HEAD~2
git commit -m 'Updated dark theme settngs in sematic UI'
git rebase --onto temp 7f80737 <branch before switch to temp>
git branch -D temp
```

Comment: Does rebase keep the history?

Comment: Yes, the below steps can keep history but the commit id will be different as before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove some changes from your branch but want to keep them so you can have them later - move them to other branch. Call it "experimental" or something like that.